# retrieving objects from boost::variant

Tags: c++, stdvector, boost-variant, apply-visitor

I tried to ask my question before, but I think the way I ask my question is not proper. so I tried again here: (still I don't know what subject would be appropriate)

first I defined

```
typedef boost::variant<point, Line, Vertex> vec_variant;
typedef std::vector<vec_variant> vec;
```

the I write my function such that depends on the case it returns point, line, 
Vertex or even a combination of them.

```
vec my_func::select_T(const mesh::section& s, const char* model) const
{
  vec new_vec;
  .
  .
  .
  .
 //loop over my lines
  else if ( strcmp(model , "Line") == 0 )
  {
    for(section::lineIterator ite = s.beginLine(); ite != s.endLine(); ++ite )
    {
      Line ed = *ite;
        Point p0 = ed.point(0);
        Point p1 = ed.point(1);
        Point p0_modified ( /* some modification */  );
        Point p1_modified ( /* some modification */  ); 

        if( /* some other conditions */ )
        {
          new_vec.push_back(ed);
          new_vec.push_back(p0_modified); //note before pushing back any point 
          new_vec.push_back(p1_modified); //first I pushed back line
        }

         else if ( /* some other conditions */ )
         {
           .
           .
           .
           vertex m = .......;
           new_vec.push_back(ed);
           new_vec.push_back(m);  //note before pushing back any point 
                                  //first I pushed back line
         }
      }
    }
  }
      return new_vec;
    }
```

so at the end we may have something like this  {ed, p0_modified, p0_modified, ed, m, ed, m, ed, p0_modified, p0_modified, ed, m, ....}
                                               {Line,Point,Point,Line,Vertex,line,Vertex,Line,Point,Point,Line,Vertex, ...}

Now I call this function in the other part of the code (different file)

```
first I defined a visitor:

    template<typename T>
    struct T_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
    {
       T_visitor(std::vector<T>& v) : zeroVector(v) {}
       template<typename U>
       void operator () (const U&) {}
       void operator () (const T& value)
       {
          zeroVector.push_back(value);
       }
    private:
       std::vector<T>& zeroVector;
    };
```

I called above function here :

```
void func_2( /*......*/ )
{
  . //we can use above visitor to store each type (point, line, Vertex) in vactor<point or line or Vertex)
  . //we do not know what the new_vec is at the end of the loop. the only thing we know is that after each line there
  . //would be either two points or one vertex
  .
  const char *model = "Edge";
  .
  .//How to find line ed and corresponded points?
  .
  create_line( Point& p0_modified, Point& p1_modified, Line& ed);    //two modified points and line
  .
  .//How to find point m and corresponded line?
  .
  create_point( m(0), m(1), m(2), Line& ed);    //point m coordinates and line
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your data structure is currently a sequence of `Point`, `Line`, and `Vertex` objects (I'm going to assume that the `Surface` in the first sentence is a typo). You also know the additional restriction that any `Line` must be followed either by two `Point`s or one `Vertex`. Now you want to use this structure.

This is possible, but it's also annoying. May I recommend that you simply change your data structure?

```
struct LineWithPoints {
  Line line;
  Point p1, p2;
};
struct LineWithVertex {
  Line line;
  Vertex v;
};
typedef boost::variant<LineWithPoints, LineWithVertex> vec_variant;
typedef std::vector<vec_variant> vec;
```

And change your code to produce this sequence instead. Then working with it becomes trivial.

Comment: Or `typedef boost::variant< std::array<Point,2>, Vertex > AfterLine; struct LineWithAfter { Line line; AfterLine after; }`.